# Crystal Reports As Web Services

Tags: c#, web-services, crystal-reports, reporting

Currently we are running reports and emailing them to our users. However we often have to change the date range to suit the user. We are now looking for a way to allow users to generate the reports via a web service.

Can anybody suggest or direct me to an example that would be able to do this.

Comment: I take it you don't have Crystal InfoView? That's exactly what the product does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create programmatically the reports using Crystal Reports, than [this MSDN article series](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227408%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [this CodeProject tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/695587/Beginners-tutorial-on-how-to-load-Crystal-Reports) could help you.

There are many ways resp. technologies to build a Web Service. One approach would be to build it using [Microsoft ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/web-api). If you want to use just ASP.NET, than this MSDN tutorial [Creating and Using an ASP.NET Web Service in Visual Web Developer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wbhsy70%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) could help you.

One good alternative to Crystal Reports is [Microsoft SQL Reporting Services (SSRS)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106.aspx). Where i work we are doing exactly the same - replacing Crystal Reports with SSRS reports. Benefits:

- reports can be viewed online from the reporting server
- reports can be also created easily from code (any .NET framework language)
- parametrised very easily
- build-in export to excel, pdf, e-mail
- personally i find the VS IDE support better, than the Crystal Reports IDE resp. plugins for VS

Comment: This is a great, well thought out reply. Thank you @pasty